# Unable to run this code still it shows no errors?

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10

void main()
{ 
    int a[SIZE], i, j, temp;

    printf("Enter 10 numbers");

    for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);

    for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<SIZE-i; j++)
        {
            if (a[j] > a[j+1])
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j+1];
                a[j+1] = temp;
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
        printf("%d", a[i]);
}
```

Further it shows :

```
prog.c:4: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’
```

so what does this mean ?

Comment: What is your code supposed to do?

Comment: Arranging a list of integer numbers

Comment: Missing braces around the `if` statement?

Comment: looks like a bubble sort, probably homework.

Comment: Argh! A `void main`! My eyes, they burn!

Comment: The language requires main to have a return type of int. Some implementations let you get away with void, but give you a warning.

Answer (score 2):

In C, `main()` returns `int`.  If the program completes successfully you return `0`, if not you return some non-zero number of your choosing.  In Unix, at least, the number that `main()` returns will be the exit code returned by the program to the command shell.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
{ 
    for(j=0; j<SIZE-i; j++)
    {  
        if(a[j]>a[j+1])          // <-   a { here?
             temp = a[j];
             a[j] = a[j+1];
             a[j+1] = temp;
 // a } here?
    }
}
```

and when `i = 0`,  `j` will be `0` to `SIZE-1`, when `j` is `SIZE-1`, `j+1` will be `SIZE`, so `a[j+1]` is `a[SIZE]`!

Answer (score 1):

It means that `main` is require to return an int, so instead of `void main()`, you should have `int main()`, and at the end, you should normally have `return 0;` to indicate normal exit.

Comment: What you're getting is a warning, not an error. At least with most compilers, that means the compiler *is* accepting your program and producing an executable from it, but *warning* you that part of what you've done may not be right or may not be the best idea (and in this case, it's right).

Answer (score 0):

Besides missing `{}` after `if` statement, you have a logical overhead too. First iteration makes sure that first element is the least and no need to check for it again in the second iteration and similarly for the rest of the elements.

```
for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
{ 
   for(j=0; j<SIZE-i; j++)
   // Start the second loop from i to SIZE.
```

Answer (score -1):

Also your i in the second for loop should be a 1 i think - ie. SIZE - 1 not SIZE - j